# Creating points using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, point

I'm new to ArcPy. I have coordinates of points

```
70°8'12.938"E  ,25°26'11.569"N 

79°10'33.945"E,  25°43'58.898"N 

80°25'46.695"E , 16°45'15.907"N 

70°6'57.527"E , 17°10'51.245"N
```

I tried below  code:

```
>>> fc=r'D:\Arcpy Practise\arcpy.gdb\Points_UTM43N'
>>> file=open(r"D:\Arcpy Practise\xy.txt","r")
>>> read=file.readlines()
>>> with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(fc,["shape@"]) as cur:
...     for line in read:
...         x,y=line.split(",")
...         pt=arcpy.Point(x,y)
...         cur.insertRow(pt)
```

code shows RuntimeError: Point: Input value is not numeric

Comment: Please [edit] the question to show what you have tried, and where you are stuck. All coding questions should contain code. You should also give an indication of what you intend to do with these objects, since `Point` and `PointGeometry` are different objects

Comment: Is there a reason you want to use arcpy instead of a tool like "Make XY Event layer"? As Vince said, if you want to use code, you'll need to provide the code you've attempted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message you're getting is describing what the problem is. Your coordinates are strings, not numeric. They'll need to be converted to Decimal Degrees, instead of Degrees, Minutes, Seconds.

The [documentation for `arcpy.Point`](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-classes/point.htm)  indicates that the x,y coordinates need to be doubles. For example, your first point will be 70.136927, 25.436547.

You can use the [Convert Coordinate Notation](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/convert-coordinate-notation.htm) tool to convert between DMS to DD.